# OpenGL: Shape changes position when display window pressed

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm having trouble when I run my program that when I press the window where my 3D shape it changes position. When I press it for the second time, the shape would disappear.

Here is what my program looks like:

```
GLsizei winWidth = 500, winHeight = 500;
int userLongitude, userLatitude;
GLenum drawStyle;
bool isSolid = false;

void keyboardFunc(unsigned char, int, int);

void init(void)
{
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

void keyboardFunc(unsigned char Key, int x, int y) {
switch (Key) {
case 's':
    //drawStyle = GLU_FILL;
    isSolid = true;

    break;
case 'w':
    //drawStyle = GLU_LINE;
    isSolid = false;
    break;
}
//cout << Key << endl;
//glutPostRedisplay();
}
void wireQuadSurfs(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

gluLookAt(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


GLUquadricObj *cylinder;
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0, 1.2, 0.8);
glRotatef(45, 1, 0, 0);
cylinder = gluNewQuadric();


//cylinder, baseRad, topRad, height, slices, stacks
//gluCylinder(cylinder, 0.6, 0.6, 1.5, userLongitude, userLatitude);
//gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_LINE);
//gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, drawStyle);

if (isSolid) {
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_FILL);
}
else {
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_LINE);
}
gluCylinder(cylinder, 0.6, 0.6, 1.5, userLongitude, userLatitude);
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
}

void winReshapeFcn(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight)
{
glViewport(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 5.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutInitWindowSize(winWidth, winHeight);
glutCreateWindow("CSC 313 HW 8 Part 2");

cout << "Enter number of longitude: ";
cin >> userLongitude;
cout << "Enter number of latitude: ";
cin >> userLatitude;
cout << "Switch between solid and wireframe views with 's' and 'w' keys" << endl;

glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunc);
init();
glutDisplayFunc(wireQuadSurfs);
glutReshapeFunc(winReshapeFcn);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

What I'm trying to do with my program is switch between the solid and wireframe of my shape. But when I click on the display window, it would change positions and then disappear from view. I'm not sure if it's because of my keyboard function or something else. Sorry for the lack of details, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Can you please describe the environment a little bit more? Maybe versions of everything? A screen capture?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initilaize the projection matrix stack with the identity matrix, before you set the orthograohic projection (see [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 5.0);
```

Note, [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) multiplies the current matrix by the orthographic projection matrix.
This means it does not assign a new 4*4 matrix, it multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix and assigns the result to the matrix stack. Every time when `winReshapeFcn` is called, the matrix on the projection matrix stack would change progressively, in the code of your question.

If you call `glLoadIdentity`, then the matrix stack is initilized by the identity matrix. The call of `glOrtho` multiplies the identity matrix by the new orthographic projection. The result is the orthographic projection itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've added `glLoadIdentity()` in but it still results in the same problem. So each time the program refreshes, `glLoadIdentity` would reset the projection coordinates? And would the `gluPostRedisplay` function affect it somehow if it was called before the 'winReshapeFcn'?

Comment: @chiyopet `gluPostRedisplay` only marks the current window as needing to be redisplayed. It does not any changes to any OpenGL state. `glLoadIdentity` does not set any coordinates, but it initializes the matrix on the matrix stack.

Comment: @chiyopet If you still have the same issue, then your question does not contain a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)